# insert operation in Binary tree error?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I am getting error in the insertion operation for the binary tree the question link is( https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-insertion ) 
my code is :

```
insert(node * root, int value)
{
    int x = 0;
    node* r = root;
    node* xx;
    while(x==0)
    {
       while(value<r->data&&r->left!=NULL)
       {
            r=r->left;
       }
       if(value<r->data&&r->left == NULL)
       {
         xx->data = value;
         r->left = xx;
         break;
       }
       while(value>r->data && r->right!=NULL)
       {
           r = r->right;
       }       
       if(value>r->data&& r->right == NULL)
       {
            xx->data = value;
            r->right =xx;
            break;
       }
    }
    return root;
}
```

The error that I am getting from the hackerrank is as follows:

Wrong Answer!
Some possible errors:

1. You returned a NULL value from the function.
2. There is a problem with your logic
3. You are printing some value from the function

Comment: `while(x==0)` infinite loop

Comment: What is the error

Comment: @User_Targaryen I am using break statement to get out of while loop .

Comment: What "error"? Describe it in full (and in your post, not the comments)

Comment: Did you bother building it offline, passing some test values and possibly debugging!?

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't know much about how to build it so I am going about attempting questions on hackerrank and learning by solving the questions under binary tree section .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you need to allocate a new node on each insertion.

Start your declaration like this:

```
node* insert(node * root, int value)
{
    node* xx = new node();
    xx->left = NULL;
    xx->right = NULL;
    xx->data = value;
```

Comment: Thanks but only one number is being inserted in this case

Comment: It does't matter.  Each node in your tree contains pointers to child nodes.  Where do you expect that memory to get allocated?

Comment: Another bug:  If you try to insert a number already in the tree, I think it will get into an infinite loop.